# Create list based on descending values and include duplicates

Tags: excel

**Excel-File**

```
   |      A       |        B          |    C   |       D         |      E     |
---|--------------|-------------------|--------|-----------------|------------|----
1  |    Product   |       Sales       |        |     Product     |    Sales   | 
---|--------------|-------------------|--------|-----------------|------------|----
2  |   Product_A  |        20         |        |     Product_D   |     100    |
3  |   Product_A  |        10         |        |     Product_D   |      90    |
4  |   Product_A  |        50         |        |     Product_B   |      80    |
5  |   Product_B  |        80         |        |     Product_A   |      50    |
6  |   Product_C  |        40         |        |     Product_D   |      50    |
7  |   Product_C  |        30         |        |     Product_D   |      50    |
8  |   Product_D  |       100         |        |     Product_C   |      40    |
9  |   Product_D  |        90         |        |     Product_C   |      30    |
10 |   Product_D  |        50         |        |     Product_A   |      20    |
11 |   Product_D  |        50         |        |     Product_D   |      10    |
12 |              |                   |        |                 |            |
```

---

In `Column A` I have list of different products with their corresponding sales in `Column B`.

1. **Products** can **appear mutliple times** in the list.
2. **Sales numbers** can be **equal for multiple products**.

Now, I want to create a descending list of the products in `Column D` and `Column E` depending on the sales in `Column B`. 
I tried to go with `=LARGE(B3:B12,1), =LARGE(B3:B12,2), ...` but it delets all duplicates from the list.

Do you have any idea what formular I need to make this list work?

Comment: Do you have Microsoft 365? If so, you can use `SORT()`.

Comment: Without Microsoft 365, i can only think using pivot tables or VBA, but not formulas....

Comment: Without `SORT()`, you'd have to use something like ROW() to break the ties (in a helper column). For instance, if sales were all integral and the total number of rows was less than 1000, you could use `=B2*1000+ROW()` as the helper column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Office 356 Solution:**

```
=SORT(A2:B11,2,-1,FALSE)
```

Including Filters:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B11,A2:A11=M2,""),2,-1,FALSE)
```

Including multiple Filters-Criterias:

```
=SORT(FILTER(A2:B11,(A2:A11=M2)*(A2:A11=M2)*(A2:A11=M2),""),2,-1,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should work in older versions.

I create a Table and am using structured references, for flexibility, but you can convert to regular addressing if you need to:

```
D2: =INDEX(Table31[Product],AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(Table31[Sales]=E2)*ROW(Table31[Sales]),COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2))-ROW(Table31[#Headers]))
E2: =LARGE(Table31[Sales],ROWS($A$1:A1))
```

Selectd `D2:E2` and fill down as far as needed

[image]

Comment: This formula is awesome!, thumbs up!