# Create descending list including duplicates and change order of columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

**Excel-File**

```
   |      A       |        B          |    C   |       D         |      E     |
---|--------------|-------------------|--------|-----------------|------------|----
1  |    Sales     |       Product     |        |     Product     |    Sales   | 
---|--------------|-------------------|--------|-----------------|------------|----
2  |      20      |     Product_A     |        |     Product_D   |     100    |
3  |      10      |     Product_A     |        |     Product_D   |      90    |
4  |      50      |     Product_A     |        |     Product_B   |      80    |
5  |      80      |     Product_B     |        |     Product_A   |      50    |
6  |      40      |     Product_C     |        |     Product_D   |      50    |
7  |      30      |     Product_C     |        |     Product_D   |      50    |
8  |     100      |     Product_D     |        |     Product_C   |      40    |
9  |      90      |     Product_D     |        |     Product_C   |      30    |
10 |      50      |     Product_D     |        |     Product_A   |      20    |
11 |      50      |     Product_D     |        |     Product_D   |      10    |
12 |              |                   |        |                 |            |
```

---

In `Column B` I have list of different products with their corresponding sales in `Column A`.

1. **Products** can **appear mutliple times** in the list.
2. **Sales numbers** can be **equal for multiple products**.

With reference to the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087262/create-list-based-on-descending-values-and-include-duplicates/69087787#69087787) I tried to create a descending list of the products in `Column D` an`d Column E` depending on the sales in `Column A` using this formula:

```
=SORT(A2:B11,2,-1,FALSE)
```

The list itself works but in a different column order. 
Instead of the products in `Column D` the sales appear in `Column D` and in `Column E` the products. 
--> The strucutre of the data scoure is copied.

Is it possible to use the `SORT` formula and change the order of the columns? 
If not is there an alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDEX()`:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:B11,2,-1),SEQUENCE(COUNT(A2:A11)),{2,1})
```

---

Current view on OP side:
Due to unknown reason only `Column D` gets filled.

[image]

Comment: When I enter this formula it looks like this: Product_D, 90, #NA, #NA, ...

Comment: Then you probably have to change the `{2,1}` to `{2\1}` @Michi

Comment: Just found the issue. When I translate the formula to German Excel the , get replaced by ; but this part {2,1} of the formula has to stay with ,