# Create descending list inlcuding duplicates based on filter criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

**Excel-File**

```
   |      A       |        B          |    C   |       D         |      E     |      F     |
---|--------------|-------------------|--------|-----------------|------------|------------|-
1  |    Sales     |       Product     |        |     Product     |    Sales   |            |
2  |      20      |     Product_A     |        |     Product_D   |     100    |  Product_D |
3  |      10      |     Product_A     |        |     Product_D   |      90    |            |
4  |      50      |     Product_A     |        |     Product_D   |      50    |            |
5  |      80      |     Product_B     |        |     Product_D   |      50    |            |
6  |      40      |     Product_C     |        |                 |            |            |
7  |      30      |     Product_C     |        |                 |            |            |
8  |     100      |     Product_D     |        |                 |            |            |
9  |      90      |     Product_D     |        |                 |            |            |
10 |      50      |     Product_D     |        |                 |            |            |
11 |      50      |     Product_D     |        |                 |            |            |
12 |              |                   |        |                 |            |            |
```

---

In `Column B` I have list of different products with their corresponding sales in `Column A`.

1. **Products** can **appear mutliple times** in the list.
2. **Sales numbers** can be **equal for multiple products**.

I want to use the value in `Cell F2` as **Filter-Criteria** to create a descending list of the products in `Column D` and `Column E` sorted by the sales in `Column A`.

---

Therefore, I tried to add the `FILTER` function to the formula from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69088087/create-descending-list-including-duplicates-and-change-order-of-columns):

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:B11,A2:A11=F2,""),2,-1),SEQUENCE(COUNT(A2:A11)),{2,1})
```

However, with this formula I get error `#VALUE`.

How do I need to modify the formula to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `COUNTIF()` inside the `SEQUENCE()`:

```
=INDEX(SORT(FILTER(A2:B11,B2:B11=F2,""),2,-1),SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(B2:B11,F2)),{2,1})
```

[image]

---

Current view on OP side: 
Due to unknown reason only `Column D` gets filled.

[image]

Comment: It creates the list in Column D but without the corresponding sales in Column E. How can I add them?

Comment: I temporarily added a screenshot from my screen in your answer. Could it be an issue with Office365 updates?

Comment: @Michi, that I can't reproduce.